How to pass cookies from client to server on a different domain using nuxt3?
I feel like this is a very common use case, but I am really struggling.
I deploy my nuxt app using cloud run, which is on https://deployed.com, however I have my own domain, so I instead access it via https://actual.com
I want to have this general flow:

I have an  tag which references a nuxt server end point
The client side cookies are automatically passed to the nuxt server end point
The nuxt server reads the cookies and grabs relevant information (e.g. tenant id)
The nuxt server calls my actual back end using the above information

This flow works perfectly when I am using https://deployed.com, however when I use https://actual.com, then the flow fails on step 3. Although I can see the client sending the cookies, when the nuxt server tries to read the cookies, there's no cookies to be read. I think this is some kind of CORS issue, but despite trying a multitude of things (allowing all origins, messing with the domain of the cookies etc.), it does not work.
E.g. one of the CORS things I tried was to add some middleware such as:
export default defineEventHandler(async (event): Promise<void> => {
  // Set CORS headers
  event.node.res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  event.node.res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  event.node.res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Cookie');
  event.node.res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  // If the request method is OPTIONS, return 204 (No Content)
  if (event.node.req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    event.node.res.statusCode = 204;
    event.node.res.end();
  }
})

Any help would be appreciated.
